# Need Help on Google Translate API

Tags: javascript, google-translate, translate

I am working on a 1 requirement where i am giving set of words in english which will be in array format as a input and output will be corresponding element in Spanish and French

for example:

Input:

```
["One", "Two", "Three"]
```

## Output:

```
["One", "french translate One "," Spanish translate One "]
["Two","french translate Two "," Spanish translate Two "]
```

How can we achieve this using google translate API using javascript.
Please advise

Comment: Looks you can translate to one target language at a time, but not two or more translated language: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google Cloud Translate API [FAQ page](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq), you can only set one target language. However, you can do a work around. By making a separate API call for each targeted language and placing the results in an array, you can make it work.

Here is an example of a solution I came up with following the [APIs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) for Node JS:

```
const Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({
  projectId: projectId,
});

//Targated languages
var targets = ['fr','es'];
var result = [];
var word;

//Recursive function
var targetLanguage = function(x)
    {
        if(x < targets.length)
        {
           translate
          .translate(word, targets[x])
          .then(results => {
            const translation = results[0];

            result.push(`${translation}`);

            //Calling the function for the next target language. 
            targetLanguage(x+1);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
          });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(result);
            result = [];
        }
    }

//Function that takes the word to be translated
function translateWord(originalWord)
{
    word = originalWord;
    result.push(word);
    targetLanguage(0);
}

//Calling the function
translateWord("One");
```